# "Column out of Range" Error when populating an Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I just started implementing this to populate an Excel sheet with some data:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

//..
ExcelWorksheet VerificationSheet_Sheet4 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetTitleHere");
int row = 0, col = 0;
VerificationSheet_Sheet4.Cells[row + 1, col].Value = "AnyStringHere"; // error here
```

However it pops an error saying *column is out of range*. Why and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Excel worksheets use 1 based indexing rather than zero based.  Thus columns and rows both start at 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 2):

As per the elaboration by @Darren Young Excel uses 1 based indexing thats where the issue is.

```
  using OfficeOpenXml;

    //..
    ExcelWorksheet VerificationSheet_Sheet4 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetTitleHere");
    int row = 1, col = 1;
    VerificationSheet_Sheet4.Cells[row + 1, col].Value = "AnyStringHere";
```